# Trying to find same digits in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to find the biggest series of digit in a row in a list which i can input. And im doing this way:

```
list = []
count_max_numbers = 0
while True:
    x = int(input('число: '))
    if x == 0:
        break
    list.append(int(x))
    max_number = max(list)

for i in list:
    if i != max_number:
        pass
    else:
        count_max_numbers += 1


current_result = 0
max_result = 0
last_seen = list[0]
longest_digit = 0

for i in list:
    if i == last_seen:
        current_result += 1
    else:
        if current_result > max_result:
            max_result = current_result
            longest_digit = i
        last_seen = i
        current_result = 1

if current_result > max_result:
    max_result = current_result
    longest_digit = i

print(f'{list}')
print(f'max number: {max_number} reapeted{count_max_numbers} times')
print(f'the biggest series: {longest_digit} repeated {max_result} times')
```

this works only with first digit in a list. But i need to work it with whole list.
For example if input (1,2,3,3,3,3,5,55)
It need to get output: the biggest series: 3 repeated 4 times
I still have a problem with output of {longest_digit} it's incorrect

Comment: Have you tried itertools.groupby? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @General Poxter i  can't input any modules for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple algorithm:

Initialize `longest = None`, `longest_digit = None`, `current = 0`, `previous_digit`, and `current_digit = None`.

Then, for each `item` in the list:

- If the item is equal to `current_digit`, increment `current` by one.
- Otherwise:

  - (A) If `current > longest`, set `longest = previous_digit` and `longest_digit = item`
  - (B) Then, reset `current` to `1` and `current_digit` to `item`
- Set `previous_digit` to `item`

At the end of the list, also do step (A) above.

Now you should have the answer in `longest` (4) and `longest_digit` (3)

Comment: made as you say it works, but shows longest_digit incorrect

Comment: @method Ok, may I suggest that you either print some diagnostic information in some places in your code so you can trace where things go wrong. You may also want to have a look at a debugger, for example https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb to be able to step through your program.
There might also be something wrong with the algorithm I suggested, of course. (I found a bug with `longest_digit`, but that wasn't really a requirement in your question anyway.
If that doesn't help, see [my test here](https://gist.github.com/andrelaszlo/409cbde5618bb89f6d1b6cec067b16e7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,3,3,3,5,55]
val_holder = {}

for val in mylist:
    if val not in val_holder.keys():
        val_holder[val] = 1
    else:
        val_holder[val] += 1

max_key = max(val_holder, key=val_holder.get)
print(max_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

My aproach to this will be using `dictionary`

```
lst = [1,2,3,3,3,3,5,55]
dict = {}
for val in lst:
    if val not in dict.keys():
        dict[val] = 1
    else:
        dict[val] = dict[val] + 1
```

Once we get the **dictionary** we sort this using the **value**

```
sorted_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda keyVal: keyVal[1], reverse=True)

print(dict[0][0])
```